# init a UIViewController in portrait and landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIViewController with a xib and when ever I am allocating it, the view and width of the UIViewController does not adjust with the orientation I am in, it is always set to portrait. Even if I am at landscape. Why is this? Here's how I am initializing it:

```
PNRWebViewController *wvController = [[PNRWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PNRWebViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:self.webViewController_.view];
```

Comment: What are your autosizing properties set to in the IB file? (the red arrows) I suspect your problem may be there.

Comment: If you select a view in IB and go to the "ruler" tab in the right panel in Xcode you'll see it. I'd look at coneybeare's answer too, good info there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a ton of reasons why this could happen. Check out the official Apple Q&A Guide on the subject:

[Why won't my UIViewController rotate with the device?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009879)

- The view controller does not implement this delegate method:
  (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
- The view controller's UIView property is embedded inside UIWindow but alongside an additional view controller.
- You have added your view controller's UIView property to UIWindow as a subview, but prematurely released it soon after.
- All child view controllers in your UITabBarController or UINavigationController do not agree on a common orientation set.
- Overriding the `-(id)init:` or `-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle` method without calling super.